# Ist ein Generalinspekteur ein General? Ein Inspekteur? Beides?

Tags: translation, meaning

Ich war darüber verwundert, dass "Generalinspekteur" auf Englisch "inspector general" heisst - nicht "general inspector".

In der Diskussion meiner [Frage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240591/why-inspector-general-and-not-general-inspector-like-german-generalinspek) dazu bei english.se fiel mir auf, dass ich den englischen Begriff implizit mit dem meiner Interpretation des deutschen Begriffes vergleiche - und der Grund meiner Frage in meiner Vorstellung von dem deutschen Begriff liegen kann.

Bisher habe ich das Wort "Generalinspekteur" interpretiert etwa als

> derjenige Inspekteur (Person in einer überwachenden Rolle), der die am meisten generelle, also weitreichendste, Überwachungs- oder Inspektionsberechtigung oder Kompetenz hat

Nun könnte man das Wort auch als

> derjenige General, der die Inspektions- oder Überwachungsberbefugnis hat

interpretieren. Allerdings ist interessant, daß wohl nicht alle Generalinspekteure Generale sind. Aber der Begriff könnte ja dennoch einen General bezeichnen, und in anderen Kontexten frei verwendet werden.

Meine Frage ist nicht so sehr, welche Personen als Generalinspekteur bezeichnet werden, sondern wie das Wort "gemeint" oder zusammengesetzt ist.

Comment: Don't worry - these terms are often confusing for native English speakers as well.  This is clear when people use plural forms that do not exist: Attorney Generals, Surgeon Generals, mother-in-laws.  These rare phrases have the adjective second, so the correct plurals are Attorneys General, Surgeons General, mothers-in-law, etc.  These terms rarely come up, so people are often surprised to hear the "correct" terms on news broadcasts, etc.

Comment: Wenn man die gleich konstruierten Begriffe *Generaldirektor* oder *Generalinspektion* betrachtet (Letzteres bedeutet anscheinend je nach Land ganz Unterschiedliches) fällt die zweite Interpretation weitgehend weg.

Answer (score 7):

General bezieht sich hier nicht auf den Rang, sondern definiert Inspekteur näher, so wie ja auch der Generalschlüssel alle Schlösser sperrt (und nicht etwa einem General gehört).

Spätestens bei den ähnlichen Begriffen *attorney general*, *postmaster general* oder *surgeon general*, wird klar, dass es hier um eine generelle Funktion geht, nicht den militärischen Rang; aber selbst im militärischen Umfeld ist bei *General-* eher selten der entsprechende Dienstgrad gemeint: eigentlich fällt mir (neben *Generalmajor*, *Generalleutnant* und *Generaloberst*) nur *Generalarzt* ein, aber da gibt es auch einen *Hauptmannarzt*, *Oberstarzt* etc.

Es gibt recht viele solcher Ausdrücke (oftmals aus romanischen Sprachen stammend) bei denen Nomen und Adjektiv  für unsere Begriffe "vertauscht" sind, im Englischen deutlich mehr als im Deutschen, wobei wir solche Begriffe aber durchaus ebenfalls kennen (*agent provocateur*, *femme fatale* etc.)

Comment: _attorney general_ und ähnliche stammen aus dem Französischen. [Hier](http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/index.php?id=0060-attorney_general&pid=mw_results) gibt es eine Erklärung dazu.

Answer (score 4):

Bei dem Wort "Generalinspekteur" liegt die Bedeutung tatsächlich auf "generell". Er steht in der Hierarchie ganz oben und ihm unmittelbar unterstellt (bei der Bundeswehr) sind die "spezifischen", der Inspekteur des Heeres, der Luftwaffe, der Marine, des Sanitätsdienstes und der Streitkräftebasis.

Bisher waren alle Bw Generalinspekteure im Rang des Generals oder des gleichwertigen Admirals. "Generalinspekteur" selbst ist kein Dienstgrad, sondern ein Amt, zu dem er ernannt wird.

Durch einen Erlass von Helmut Schmidt 1970 wird der Generalinspekteur definiert als "Gesamtverantwortlicher für die Bundeswehrplanung im Verteidigungsministerium". Der Posten wurde seit damals zwar reformiert, von dort stammt aber der Name.

Heutzutage ist er schlicht der höchste Soldat in der Hierarchie, Vorgesetzter für alle Soldaten, dem Verteidigungsminister direkt unterstellt.